# How to find the general term of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the following recurrence problem:
\begin{align}
d_{i-1} &= 2\varphi_{i+1}+4\varphi_i + 8d_i-7d_{i+1} - F \left( \delta_{i,N} + \delta_{i,N+1} \right) \, , \\
\varphi_{i-1} &= -7\varphi_{i+1}-16\varphi_{i} + 24 \left( d_{i+1}-d_{i} \right) + F \left( \delta_{i,N} + \delta_{i,N+1} \right) \, , 
\end{align}
where $d_i, i \in \{2, \cdots , N+1\}$ represent displacements, $\varphi_i$ inclinations, and $F$ is a known force acting at the nodes $N$ and $N+1$.

We require by the system symmetry that $d_{N+1}=d_N = d_\mathrm{C}$ and $\varphi_N = -\varphi_{N+1}= \varphi_\mathrm{C}$, where $d_\mathrm{C}$ and $\varphi_\mathrm{C}$ are still to be determined from the boundary conditions:

$d_1 = 0$ (zero displacement) and $2\varphi_1+\varphi_2 = 3d_2$ (zero torque)

In order to proceed, i have tried to first determine $d_{N-1}$ and $\varphi_{N-1}$ from the system above, and then $d_{N-2}$ and $\varphi_{N-2}$, etc... in a recursive way and then try to find out the general term of the resulting sequences.

For the term $N-1$, we obtain
\begin{align}
d_{N-1} &= d_\mathrm{C}+2\varphi_\mathrm{C}-F \, \\
\varphi_{N-1} &= -9\varphi_\mathrm{C}+3F \, .
\end{align}

Analogously, we get for the term $N-2$
\begin{align}
d_{N-2} &= d_\mathrm{C}-18\varphi_\mathrm{C}+4F \, \\
\varphi_{N-2} &= 89\varphi_\mathrm{C}-24F \, .
\end{align}

I was wondering whether there is a particular way to figure out the general term of such sequence.

Any help or suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Well, how are you producing those coefficients?  In a rough way, it looks like you are just multiplying by $-10$ each time, or $-9.9$ to be more precise.  but of course that's only an approximation.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the comment -- i use for that a recurrence formula obtained from a finite difference scheme.

Comment: You have a recurrence that defines them?  What recurrence is that?

Comment: @lulu alright-- i will elaborate a bit on the question. Thanks

Comment: @lulu the question has just been modified. Your comments and answers welcome

Comment: You can write the problem as one linear system $AX=B$ with $X=(\phi_0, \ldots,\phi_{N-1},d_0,\ldots,d_{N-1})$ and $A$ an explicit matrix.

Comment: @Delta-u Thanks for the hint. The system for a given value of $N$ can be formulated but here i am more interested in the solution for an arbitrary value of $N$. The recurrence approach seems to be more suitable for such systems

Comment: If $i=N+1,$ then the values $d_{N+2}$ and $\varphi_{N+2}$ exist. Is the index $N+2$ correct for the task?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thanks for the comment. Actually this is a chain of particles and by symmetry $d_{N+2} = d_{N-1}$ and $d_{N+3}=d_{N-2}$. In contrast, $\varphi_{N+2} = -\varphi_{N-1}$ and $\varphi_{N+3}=-\varphi_{N-2}$, etc...

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov ... and ultimately, $d_{2N}=d_1=0$ and $\varphi_{2N}=-\varphi_1$

Comment: Can you check my system? I plan the further moving.

Comment: Ready. Waiting to comments, especially about results.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thanks a lot for your effort. i've just seen the second approach which looks better that the former one -- i will have a thorough read and get back to you

Comment: You are welcome! The task is nice. Also I left some routine work (linked with the coefficiens calculation and the complex verification).

Comment: See also [another recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845177/can-we-solve-this-recurrence-relation/2854640?noredirect=1#comment5892929_2854640)

Comment: I mean that $d_i$ and $\varphi_i$ possibly can be splitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again to Yuri for the helpful insights. I can say that I have now found the solution to my problem.

First of all, let us define $D_i = d_i-d_{i-1}$, in the same way as Yuri did, and let us get a recurrence equation that involves $\varphi_i$ only.

Actually, original problem (which is equivalent to the one stated above) was
\begin{align}
d_{i+1}-2d_i+d_{i-1} - \frac{1}{4} \left( \varphi_{i+1}-\varphi_{i-1}\right) + F \left( \delta_{i, N} + \delta_{i, N+1} \right) &=0\, , \\
d_{i+1}-d_{i-1} - \frac{1}{3} \left( \varphi_{i+1}+4\varphi_i+\varphi_{i-1} \right) &= 0 \, .
\end{align}

Accordingly, it can easily be shown that for $0 <i <N$,
\begin{align}
D_{i+1}-D_i &= \frac{1}{4} \left( \varphi_{i+1}-\varphi_{i-1} \right) \, , \\
D_{i+1}+D_i &= \frac{1}{3} \left( \varphi_{i+1}+4\varphi_i+\varphi_{i-1} \right) \, .
\end{align}

This leads to
\begin{align}
D_i = \frac{7}{24} \varphi_i + \frac{1}{24} \varphi_{i-2} + \frac{2}{3} \varphi_{i-1}  =
\frac{1}{24} \varphi_{i+1}+\frac{7}{24} \varphi_{i-1} + \frac{2}{3} \varphi_i  \, , \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{align}
or 
$$
\frac{1}{24} \left( \varphi_{i+1}-\varphi_{i-2} \right)
+\frac{3}{8} \left( \varphi_i-\varphi_{i-1} \right) =0\, .
$$

Using Yuri's powerful approach, and posing $\varphi_i = A/p^i$ yields
$$
p^3+9p^2-9p-1=0 \, , 
$$
whose solutions are $p=1$ and $p=-5\pm 2 \sqrt{6}$.

Finally, 
$$
\varphi_i = C_1 + C_2 \left(-5-2\sqrt{6}\right)^i + C_3 \left(-5+2\sqrt{6}\right)^i \, .
$$
(again, by noting that $\left(-5-2\sqrt{6}\right)\left(-5+2\sqrt{6}\right)=1$.)

Therefore, 
$$
d_i 
=D_i + D_{i-1} + \cdots + D_2 =
\sum_{n=2}^{n=i} D_n \, , 
$$
where the expression of $D_n$ follows readily from Eq. \eqref{1}, and using the fact that $d_1=0.$

The final expression read
$$
D_i = C_1 + 
C_2 \left( -1+\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} \right) \left( -5-2\sqrt{6} \right)^i + 
C_3 \left( -1-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} \right) \left( -5+2\sqrt{6} \right)^i \, ,
$$
and
$$
d_i = (i-1)C_1 + 
C_2 \left( -1+\frac{5\sqrt{6}}{12} \right)
\left[ 49+20\sqrt{6}-\left( -5-2\sqrt{6} \right)^{i+1} \right] + 
C_3 \left( 1+\frac{5\sqrt{6}}{12} \right)
\left[ -49+20\sqrt{6}+\left( -5+2\sqrt{6} \right)^{i+1} \right] \, .
$$

Clearly, $d_1=0$.
Finally, at this point, the 3 unknown coefficients can readily be determined from the 3 boundary conditions.

> I have checked that the solution is very well behaved and is in full agreement with the numerical solution.

Comment: Congratulations, now I can say with confidence that I had a brilliant student.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thanks :) Then no one apart from his teacher will deserve the bounty :) (on Monday)

Answer (score 4):

$$\mathbf{\color{green}{The\ linear\ approach}}$$

As it follows from the comments, the issue task can be detalized in the form of
\begin{cases}
d_{i-1} = 2\varphi_{i+1}+4\varphi_i + 8d_i-7d_{i+1}\\[4pt]
\varphi_{i-1} = -7\varphi_{i+1}-16\varphi_{i} + 24 \left( d_{i+1}-d_{i} \right) \\[4pt]
i=2,3\dots N-1\\[4pt]
d_1 = 0\\[4pt]
2\varphi_1+\varphi_2 = 3d_2\\[4pt]
d_{N-1} = 2\varphi_{N+1}+4\varphi_N + 8d_N-7d_{N+1} - F\\[4pt]
\varphi_{N-1} = -7\varphi_{N+1}-16\varphi_{N} + 24 \left( d_{N+1}-d_{N}\right) + F\\[4pt]
d_{N} = 2\varphi_{N-1}+4\varphi_{N+1} + 8d_{N+1}-7d_{N-1} - F\\[4pt]
\varphi_{N} = -7\varphi_{N-1}-16\varphi_{N+1} + 24 \left( d_{N-1}-d_{N+1}\right) + F\\[4pt]
d_{N+1}=d_N\\[4pt]
\varphi_{N+1} = -\varphi_{N},\tag{I}  
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
d_{i-1} - 8d_i - 4\varphi_i + 7d_{i+1} - 2\varphi_{i+1} = 0\\[4pt]
\varphi_{i-1} + 24d_i + 16\varphi_{i} - 24d_{i+1} + 7\varphi_{i+1} = 0 \\[4pt]
i=2,3\dots N-1\\[4pt]
d_1 = 0\\[4pt]
2\varphi_1 - 3d_2 + \varphi_2 = 0\\[4pt]
d_{N-1} - d_N - 2\varphi_N = - F\\[4pt]
\varphi_{N-1} + 9\varphi_{N} = F.\tag{II}  
\end{cases}
This gives the linear system
$$A\overrightarrow v=\overrightarrow f,\tag{III}$$
where
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&-3&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&-8&-4&7&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&24&16&-24&7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&-8&-4&7&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&24&16&-24&7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&-8&-4&7&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&24&16&-24&7&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&&&&&&&&&\dots&&&&&&\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&-8&-4&7&-2\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&24&16&-24&7\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&-1&-2\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&9\\
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$
\overrightarrow v=\begin{pmatrix}
d_1\\\varphi_1\\d_2\\\varphi_2\\\vdots\\d_{N-1}\\\varphi_{N-1}\\d_N\\\varphi_N
\end{pmatrix},
\overrightarrow f=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\0\\-F\\F
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Methods for solving $n$-diagonal SLAE $(n=6)$ are well known.

$$\mathbf{\color{green}{Common\ solution}}$$

Let
\begin{cases}
d_{i-1} - 8d_i + 7d_{i+1} = 4\varphi_i + 2\varphi_{i+1}\\[4pt]
\varphi_{i-1} + 16\varphi_{i} + 7\varphi_{i+1} = -24d_i + 24d_{i+1}\\[4pt]
i=2,3\dots N-1\\[4pt]
d_1 = 0\\[4pt]
2\varphi_1 - 3d_2 + \varphi_2 = 0\\[4pt]
d_{N-1} - d_N - 2\varphi_N = - F\\[4pt]
\varphi_{N-1} + 9\varphi_{N} = F,\tag1  
\end{cases}
Looking for the solution in the form of
$$d_i = Ap^{-i},\quad\varphi_i=Bq^{-i}.\tag2$$
we get the system
\begin{cases}
Ap^{-i-1}(p^2-8p+7) = Bq^{-i-1}(4q+2) \\
24Ap^{-i-1}(1-p) = Bq^{-i-1}(q^2+16q+7),\tag3
\end{cases}

which leads to the relation
$$\dfrac{d_i}{\varphi_i} = \frac pq\frac{4q+2}{p^2-8p+7} = \frac pq\frac{q^2+16q+7}{24(1-p)},\tag4$$
where
$$(p^2-8p+7)(q^2+16q+7) + 48(p-1)(2q+1)=0,$$
or
$$(p-1)\left((p-7)q^2+16(p-1)q + 7p-1\right) = 0,$$
with the solutions
$$\left[\begin{align}
&p=1\\
&p=7,\quad q=-\frac12\\[4pt]
&p=q=-5\pm2\sqrt6,
\end{align}\right.\tag5$$
wherein third and fourth solutions obtained, using additional condition $p=q$, which allows to hold the ratio $(4).$

Formulas $(5)$ and $(4)$ lead to the common solution in the form of
$$\begin{align}
&\binom{d_i}{\varphi_i} = C_1\binom{1}{0}+C_27^{-i}\binom{7}{-96}\\[4pt]
&+C_3(-5-2\sqrt6)^{i}\binom1{2\sqrt6}+C_4(-5+2\sqrt6)^{i}\binom1{-2\sqrt6},
\end{align}\tag6$$
(using the identity $(-5+2\sqrt6)(-5-2\sqrt6)=1$).

Coefficients $C_i$ can be defined from the boundary conditions.

$$\mathbf{\color{green}{Modified\ solution.}}$$

The previous model has a resonant solution $(p=1).$ To avoid this situation, should be used another basis.

Let
$$D_i=d_{i}-d_{i-1},\quad d_1=0,\tag7$$
then
\begin{cases}
-D_{i} + 7D_{i+1} = 4\varphi_i + 2\varphi_{i+1}\\[4pt]
\varphi_{i-1} + 16\varphi_{i} + 7\varphi_{i+1} = 24D_{i}\\[4pt]
i=2,3\dots N-1\\[4pt]
2\varphi_1 - 3D_2 + \varphi_2 = 0\\[4pt]
D_{N} + 2\varphi_N = + F\\[4pt]
\varphi_{N-1} + 9\varphi_{N} = F,\tag8  
\end{cases}
Looking for the solution in the form of
$$D_i = Ap^{-i},\quad\varphi_i=Bp^{-i}.\tag9$$
we get the system
\begin{cases}
A(7-p) = B(4p+2) \\
24A = B(p^2+16p+7),\tag{10}
\end{cases}

which leads to the relation
$$\dfrac{D_i}{\varphi_i} = \frac{4p+2}{7-p},\tag{11}$$
where
$$(p-7)(p^2+16p+7)+96p+48=0,$$
$$(p - 1) (p^2 + 10 p + 1) = 0,$$
with the solutions
$$\left[\begin{align}
&p_1=1,\quad D_i=\varphi_i\\
&p_2=-5+2\sqrt6,\quad D_i=\dfrac{\sqrt6-2}2\varphi_i\\
&p_3=-5-2\sqrt6,\quad  D_i=-\dfrac{\sqrt6+2}2\varphi_i.
\end{align}\right.\tag{12}$$

Formulas $(9)$ and $(12)$ lead to the common solution in the form of
$$\begin{align}
&\binom{D_i}{\varphi_i} = C_1\binom{1}{1}+C_2(-5-2\sqrt6)^{i}\binom{\sqrt6-2}2+C_3(-5+2\sqrt6)^{i}\binom{\sqrt6+2}{-2}
\end{align}\tag{13}$$
(using the identity $(-5+2\sqrt6)(-5-2\sqrt6)=1$).

Coefficients $C_i$ can be defined from the boundary conditions and then  the values of $d_i$ can be calculafed using $(7).$

$$\mathbf{\color{green}{Analogies}}$$

Are known the formulas
$$1-\binom{n}{1}2^t+\binom{n}{2}n3^t+\dots+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}n^t = 0,\quad t<n\tag{A1}$$
and 
$$\Delta^nf(x) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^n(-1)^{n-m}f(x+m)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^k \binom{r}{k}\Delta r^{n+k}f(x).\tag{A2}$$
This leads to the some analogies between the linear recurrence relations and the linear DEs.

$\mathbf{Analogy 1.}$

The ODE
$$y'''+ay''+by'=R(x)\tag{A3}$$
does not contain the term with $cy$ and can be simplified using the substitution $Y=y'.$

This analogy is the hint to use the substitution $D=d_i-d_{i-1}.$

$\mathbf{Analogy 2.}$

Solution of the OOE $(A3)$ is the sum of the common solution of the homogenius ODE and the partial solution of the origin ODE.

The common solution can be defined using the substitution $y=e^{kx}.$

This analogy is the hint to use the approach with $D=q^n.$

Btw, the negative degree were used situatively and is not obligate.

$\mathbf{Analogy 3.}$

The partial solution of ODE $(3)$ with the polynomial RHS usually can be found as the same order polynomial with the unknown coefficients.

On the other hand, the ODE
$$y'''+ay''+by'= F\tag{A4}$$
already has the common solution $y=C$ (the resonant case), so the form $y_p=Dx$ is usually applied.

Hint is clear, but the analogy isn't. Maybe, the formulas $(1)$ are the second hint?

This is the main.

Comment: The original solution (without the $C_2$ term) is correct and satisfies the recurrence equations (although we have 3 unknown coeffs and 4 BC's). The modified version does not seem to satisfy these recurrence equations. Any way, thanks for teaching me this approach -- i should now continue digging into it myself...

Comment: @MickhausenStIlgenSandhausen Without the second term, we have the overdefined system. Modified approach is the correct way to eliminate the first one, but it requires to calculate $d_i$ using $(7).$

Comment: Indeed. i think that the third and forth boundary conditions (with the corrected $F$ sign) are in fact the same :) i am happy -- thank for helping. The system is now beautifully solved

Comment: @MickhausenStIlgenSandhausen It was my first experience for two unknowns. The work was interersting for me too. Good luck!

Comment: Sadly enough, i am still enable to determine the right coeffs from the boundary conditions. The exponential nature of the solution lead to large quantities. A second bounty of 100 has just started

Comment: Yuri, i think that i've found the solution of the problem. Please refer to the answer i've just posted

Answer (score 1):

Except for i=N and i=N+1, you can write the recursion for a 4-vector
$$\vec{v}_i=(d_i,d_{i-1},\phi_i,\phi_{i-1})^t$$
and a 4x4 matrix $A$.  Write $d_i$ and $\phi_i$ in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, then deal with the boundary conditions at $0,N$ and $N+1$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. More clarifications here would be helpful